# Android Studio on Mac - New Empty Project doesn't use the latest compileSDK in gradle build files

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio on Mac, updated to the latest version. When I create a new empty project, my `build.gradle.kts` file sets:
`compileSdk = 33`

This causes an issue when I build because some libraries require SDK 34. I have SDK 34 installed from my SDK Manager, as shown below. However, for some reason, new projects default to SDK 33.

I can work around it by editing the compileSdk to 34 and syncing build files for every new project (as found in another solution).

Is there a way to control which compileSdk is used by default to avoid the issue entirely?

[My SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHDro.png)

Thanks much!